# Getting number format excpetion

Tags: java, string, long-integer, formatexception

Unable parsing below number.

```
Long.parseLong("1000.00".length() > 0 ? "1000.00" : "0")
```

While parsing "1000.00" then getting number format exception.

How to parse "1000.00" this string into long in java?

Comment: Long does not have decimal points.

Comment: `long`s are integral numbers. `"1000"` would work. `"1000.00"` has a fractional portion (which is zero, but still), which will not.

Comment: Why its downvoted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`long`s are integral numbers. `"1000"` would work. `"1000.00"` has a fractional portion (which is zero, but still), which will not.

> How to parse "1000.00" this string into long in java?

In the general case, you can't; a `long` can't store a fractional portion.

Now, in your specific example, the fractional portion is zero, so you *could* just remove it:

```
long result = Long.parseLong("1000.00".split("\\.")[0]);
```

Or you could parse it as a double and then truncate it:

```
long result = (long)Double.parseDouble("1000.00");
```

...but again, just beware that `long` is an integral type that doesn't support fractional values.

Comment: The whole code is nonsense. Why is he not using the actual `length` of the String and that's it...

Answer (score 0):

remove the dot or decimal part of that string, a Long is in fact an integer with 64 bit capacity...

```
System.out.println(Long.parseLong("1000.00".length() > 0 ? "1000" : "0"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(long)Double.parseDouble("1000.00".length() > 0 ? "1000.00" : "0")
```